# Migrate big MySQL database respecting the AutoIncrement holes

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, migrate

I have a MySQL database 5.1.49 with 150+ tables on third party hosting provider. Most of the tables have AUTO_INCREMENT primary key and holes in the values.
When I try to generate a script for the database from phpMyAdmin it times out since the database is big.
When I try to migrate the database using MySql Workbench it fails with a Workbench bug.

Is there a tool that can migrate big MySQL databases while respecting disordered and having holes auto increment fields?

Comment: Yes, the mysqldump tool http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: I doubt my hosting provider supports console commands execution.

Comment: Your hosting provider only needs to support 'connecting to the db'.